# Equations for 3D waves from an Impulsive Point Source

Tags: waves, dirac-delta-distributions

I think there should be two ways of writing the equation for the impulsive spherical wave
from an impulsive point source at the origin, say $\delta(t) \delta(r)$:

$$(4\pi ct)^{-1} \delta(r-ct) \tag{1}$$

$$(4\pi ct)^{-1} \delta(t-r/c) \tag{2}$$

But these are not the same.  In (1) the Delta Function has dimension 1/[L] and in (2) the Delta Function has dimension 1/[T].

Also

$$(4\pi ct)^{-1} \delta(r-ct) = (4\pi ct)^{-1} \delta(c(r/c-t)) =(4\pi ct)^{-1} (1/c)\delta((t-r/c))$$

so the two equations differ by (1/c).

**My question is which is right and why?**

Why would one be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wave from an impulsive point source is the *Green's function* $G(\vec{r},t)$ for the inhomogenous wave equation.  In other words, if we wish to solve the equation
$$
- \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} + \nabla^2 \psi = \rho(\vec{r},t),
$$
we can do so by solving the related equation 
$$
- \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial t^2} + \nabla^2 G = \delta^3(\vec{r}) \delta(t). \tag{A}
$$
in a distributional sense.
By convention, the Green's function is usually taken to be the solution to this equation (in a distributional sense) with a delta function of *unit* weight on the right-hand side. This allows us to then find the solution of a more general inhomogeneous equation
via integration:
$$
\psi(\vec{r},t) = \iiiint d^3\vec{r}' dt' G(\vec{r} - \vec{r}',t-t') \rho(\vec{r}',t'). \tag{B}
$$
(This can be proven by simply applying the wave operator to the right-hand side and bringing the derivatives inside the integral.)  If we had used a different weight for the delta functions on the right-hand side, then this equation would require extra pre-factors to compensate.

So which one is right?  Dimensionally, the right-hand side of (A) has dimensions of $[\text{length}]^{-3} [\text{time}]^{-1}$, and so by this logic the dimensions of $G$ should be $[\text{length}]^{-1} [\text{time}]^{-1}$.  In your question, version (2) has the right units, and so it would be the correct Green's function for this equation.

Of course, if you defined your inhomogeneous wave equation differently---for example, something like
$$
- \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} + c^2 \nabla^2 \psi = \rho(\vec{r},t)
$$
then the appropriate Green's function would be the solution to *this* equation with the right-hand side replaced by a unit-weight delta-function.  Via the same dimensional arguments as above, the correct Green's function (so that the solution is still given by eq. (B)) would be
$$
G(\vec{r},t) = \frac{1}{4\pi c^3 t} \delta(t-r/c).  
$$

Comment: Super answer--thanks.  I am surprised that the Green's fn depends on the algebraic arrangement of the wave equation.

Comment: Very roughly speaking, the Green’s function acts as the “inverse” of a differential operator. From that perspective, it’s not entirely surprising that multiplying the operator by a constant changes the Green’s function, just as multiplying a matrix by a constant changes that inverse.

Comment: I see--like in $TT^{-1}=\delta$